# .htaccess rewrite to another port

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, lighttpd

I have a joomla setup in my /home/joomla directory.
I installed both Apache and Lighttpd
i have configured Lighttpd to proxy only static files, and lighttpd is listening on port 81.
Now what i want is

whenever request for static files are made, instead of going to

> www.domain.com/whatever/bg.jpg

it should redirect to

> domain.com:81/whatever/bg.jpg

using .htaccess

also notice that www.domain.com changed to domain.com

please please i need a quick help for it :)

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? Hosting the static files by both Apache and Lighttpd has no advantage that I can think of. It just makes it heavier for the server and thus slower.

Comment: i am just relaying all static files through lighttpd, i have also made configuration to not to parse any dynamic content, such as php or html, cause they are already served by apache. instead all the images, videos etc, are being parsed from lighttpd , now incase some static content fails to obey htacces, because of the SEF system in Joomla, then the failsafe method of serving it through apache is also present :)

Am i doing correct??

Comment: also i have tried using

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css)$ http://domain.com:81/$1 [P,QSA,L]

but it returns 404 not found error, :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright i found out the way :)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css)$ http://domain.com:81/$1 [P,QSA,L]
```

Learned a lot about htaccess files in one day :)

Answer (score 0):

try this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(directory)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com:81/$1 [P,QSA,L]
```

Comment: I want only static files which is not neccesarily present in a directory, rewrite codition must check for jpg, css, flv, gif, etc and if itsz true then " RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com:81/$1 [P,QSA,L] "

Comment: even if i change the above to
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css)$ http://domain.com:81/$1 [P,QSA,L]

It returns 404 error......