# how to redirect certain url to port using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect url as  abc.xyz.org to 192.168.xx.yy:abcd using htaccess.
tried using following in htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 192.168.xx.yy:abcd [P,R=301,L]
```

but this rule isn't taking the port number.What should I do?
i tried

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 192.168.xx.yy:abcd[b] [P,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222725/htaccess-rewrite-to-another-port

Comment: @vee Yeah I tried this too .. but to no avail ... it just don't access the port

Comment: There's some possibility that the client is redirected to `192.168.xx.yy:abcd` before it's immediately redirected to 192.168.xx.yy. Press `F12` in your browser (if supports), and see the network section carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.168.0.1:1234/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.168.xx.yy:abcd [P,R=301,L]
```

Your using [P] flag. Make sure mod_proxy is enabled. In this [doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) it says `Note: mod_proxy must be enabled in order to use this flag.` To enable `mod_proxy` give command

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
```

Then restart `apache`

If you can not enable mod_proxy `[P]` flag is of no use. Then your rewrite rule will be

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.168.xx.yy:abcd [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @sammy enabled mod_proxy?

Comment: how to enable it .. searched it but can't get any idea. Help please.

Comment: @sammy details in the answer.

Comment: where to put sudo a2enmod proxy. Confused

Comment: Also remove the [P] flag for now as you can not enable mod_proxy.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44301/discussion-between-chanchal118-and-sammy)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php$1 [R=301, L]
```